# Problem on Displaying a view on lock screen using windowmanager

Tags: android, android-service, android-view, android-windowmanager

I have float icon that must be stays on top of all activities and must be shown when device is on locked state. I maintain the screen on/off state through broadcast receiver. I have code it to hide when unlocked state and show on device locked state. But floating action not shown while screen off state. I have kept log over onReceive method, log has been shown while screen ON/OFF. Some of tutorials suggest to kept WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR while I kept this flag then the app get crashed throwing permission denied. And When I replace TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR with TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY then the floating doesn't shown on locked scree. Can any one suggest me, how to resolve this problem? 
9
I have a float icon that stays on top of all activities, but when the device get locked it disappear until the device get unlocked.

Another meaning, I want to display a view (FloatIcon) on lock screen using windowmanager from service.

This is my code so far.

```
package com.example.accessibilityservice;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class FloatingIconService extends Service {

    private FloatingIconReceiver mReceiver;

    private boolean isShowing = false;

    private WindowManager windowManager;

    public ImageView icon;

    private WindowManager.LayoutParams params;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.i("onStart", "FloatingIconService");

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        //add icon and its properties
        icon = new ImageView(this);
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_home);

        icon.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        icon.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                Log.i("onStart", "FloatingIconService when long press on icon");
                ((Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(1000);

                /*Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dashboard.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                startActivity(i);*/
                return true;
            }
        });

        //set parameters for the icon
        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 10;
        params.y = 100;
        //Register receiver for determining screen off and if user is present
        mReceiver = new FloatingIconReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
        registerReceiver((BroadcastReceiver) mReceiver, filter);
        Log.i("onStart", "FloatingIconService2");
        icon.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;

            private int initialY;

            private float initialTouchX;

            private float initialTouchY;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        initialX = params.x;
                        initialY = params.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(icon, params);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public class FloatingIconReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("TEST", "TEST");
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                //if screen is turn off show the icon
                if (!isShowing) {
                    windowManager.addView(icon, params);
                    isShowing = true;
                }
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
                //Handle resuming events if user is present/screen is unlocked remove the icon immediately
                if (isShowing) {
                    windowManager.removeViewImmediate(icon);
                    isShowing = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i("onStart", "FloatingIconService3");
        if (mReceiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        }

        //remove view if it is showing and the service is destroy
        if (isShowing) {
            windowManager.removeViewImmediate(icon);
            isShowing = false;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Activity class code:

```
 startService(new Intent(getApplication(), FloatingIconService.class));
```

Manifest File:

```
<receiver android:name=".FloatingIconService$FloatingIconReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" />
        <service android:name=".FloatingIconService" />
```

Comment: did you find the solution to this?

Comment: @Pierre not yet. If you found any solution then please share it.

Comment: Maybe you can try "TYPE_PHONE"?